# Selenium Hub deployed on kubernetes returning 504 error while accessing Application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, selenium-chromedriver

I have "selenium hub" and "selenium node chrome" running on Kubernetes. I have network policy to access Selenium hub from outside. From UI automation application I could able to connect to Selenium hub using RemoteWebDriver but while it is trying access the application I am getting 504 gateway timeout error. Application that I am trying access I have included that in the network policy Egress section for application "selenium node chrome".

When I tried to access the application from inside the "selenium node chrome" POD I could able to connect to that application which means my Network policy looks correct. So not sure why it can not connect from the Automation application.

Any pointers for this issue will be highly appreciated.